# RegEx to find a keyword & print whole line with matches

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I need to create a regexp  to be used in python where a keyword is to be matched in output & whole line with exact matches should be displayed, kindly assist

```
Some_output = "hello how are you something. \nhello how are you2 something.\nhello how are you3 
something."
Search_String ="you2"
Expected Output - how are you2 something.
vv = re.findall(r'.*you2.*',Some_output)
print(vv)  - returns nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

I would tokenize/split your input into a list of sentences, then use a list comprehension to find matching sentences:

```py
inp = "hello how are you something. \nhello how are you2 something.\nhello how are you3 something."
sentences = inp.split('\n')
search = 'you2'
matches = [s for s in sentences if re.search(r'\b' + search + r'\b', s)]
print(matches)  # ['hello how are you2 something.']
```

Comment: No, I can't, because your edit invalidates both of the helpful answers which have been given here.  Please don't dramatically change your question after others have invested time in answering it.

Answer (score 1):

First, convert the string into a list then find any line matches with `Search_String` tag.

```
Some_output = "hello how are you something. \nhello how are you2 something.\nhello how are you3 something."
LINES = Some_output.split('\n')
Search_String = "you2"
for LINE in LINES:
    if re.search(r'\b{}\b'.format(Search_String), LINE):
        print(LINE)
```

Comment: have rephrased the questions can u plz check now